# implement sorting and function calling

Tags: java

i'm trying to sort an array of numbers

```
public class Sort {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int [] array = new int[10];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ ) {
        array[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*100+1));
        }
    Arrays.sort( array );
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ ) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
  } 
}
```

and it worked fine, then i tried to put it in function and calling it from the main function

```
public class Sort {
    public void Implement () {
     int [] array = new int[10];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ ) {
            array[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*100+1));
            }
    Arrays.sort( array );
    }
}
   public static void main(String[] args){
        Sort s = new Sort();
        s.Implement (array);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
```

then all the errors appears in the for loop despite it is correct, what the problem here ?

Comment: You either need to pass the `array` variable from `main` to `s.implement(array)` or return it from `s.implement`

Comment: i thought i pass it when i wrote this line 's.Implement (array);'

Comment: you did, but the `array` variable itself doesn't exist in the `main` scope, so you need to declare it

Answer (score 0):

Signature(formal parameter) of `Implement ()` mehtod is `void` in its definition. However, you are trying to pass an actual argument which is `array` in your example case to the method in `main()`. That's why you get the compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in using `s.Implement (array);`.

Following are the errors in your code:

- `Sort.Implement()` is not expecting any argument but you are passing one.
- In line `s.Implement (array);`, you have not created variable `array`. But you are using it in this line and latter.

Following is corrected working example. See it [working here](https://ideone.com/oY5aRu):

```
class Sort 
{
    public int[] Implement () {
        int [] array = new int[10];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ ) {
            array[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*100+1));
        }
        Arrays.sort( array );

        return array;
    }
}

class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args){
        Sort s = new Sort();
        int[] array = s.Implement ();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Remarks:** Base on your code and use of *methods*, it seems that you are new to programming. So take some time to understand *concepts* first.